# Jquery datatables operations based on row index

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add some texts and links on rows on a datatable based on row index.

this is my datatable initialization part

```
 <script>
var datatablecompanyuser = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "paging": false
    });

    var dataSourceUrl = "@Url.Action("CompanyUsersList", "Settings")";
    datatablecompanyuser = $('#datatablecompanyuser').dataTable({
        info: false,
        ajax: {
            "url": dataSourceUrl,
            "type": "GET",

        },
        columns: [
            {
                "data": "Id",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return "<label><input type='checkbox' value='" + data + "' name='chkGrid'><span class='text'></span></label>";
                }
            },
            { "data": "Fullname" },
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "CitizenIdNo" },
            {
                "data": "CreateDate",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return moment(parseInt(data.substr(6))).format('DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm');
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "Id",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    var table = $('#datatablecompanyuser').DataTable();
                    if (table.row().index() == 0){
                        return "<label>A</label>"}
                    else {
                        return "<label>B</label>";
                    }
                }
            },
            { "data": "Id" },


        ],
        language: {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/i18n/Turkish.json"
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

I'm trying to add text "A" on first row and "B" on other rows.

As seen on code piece above, I tried doing something like this on the corresponding column.

```
{
                        "data": "Id",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            var table = $('#datatablecompanyuser').DataTable();
                            if (table.row().index() == 0){
                                return "<label>A</label>";}
                            else {
                                return "<label>B</label>";
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

But every row gets A. I'm doing something wrong but can't understand what.

I will need the same row index determining for the next column to include a link (or not) but I guess if I can solve it here, rest will be easy.

Comment: You should specify the row, try using `table.row(row).index() == 0`

Comment: `table.row(row).index() == 0` or directly can't you access index from the row variable in the callback??

Comment: I don't know much about JS and jQuery sadly. I don't know if I can do it or not. Also above mentioned methods are all returning "A" too.

Comment: Could you try instead `if (row.index() == 0)` ?

Comment: Gives "TypeError: row.index is not a function" error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing another parameter in the render function called `meta` and this stores the row and column index. See the [JQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) documentation for more info on the render function parameters.

```
function (data, type, row, meta) {
     if (meta.row == 0){
         return "<label>A</label>";}
     else {
         return "<label>B</label>";
     }
}
```

As stated in the documentation the meta parameter was only added in version 1.10.1

Comment: Works! Thanks for the infomation and answer